# Percentage using Random

Tags: java, random

Today I created a function which generates a `random` number (0, 1, 2 or 3).
But I want yo have a percetage function.

I would like to apply a percentage to every chance to which the generated numbers fall.
Example: 0 will have 60% chance of being drawn, the number 1 19%, ...

```
 public void GenerGame(){

        Random r = new Random();
        int game = r.nextInt(max - min +1);

        if (game == 0){
            // do something
        }
        else if (game == 1){
            // do something
        }
        else if (game == 2){
            // do something
        }
        else {
            // do something
        }
 }
```

Can I do it by using `Random`?

Comment: This is not a question related to Android. This is basic Java programming.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+weighted+random

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can definitely do this by re-thinking your RNG.

If you change the random generation range to 0-99, you can think of this as a *range* of percentages produced, and hence prescribe various behaviors in those ranges.

```
public void GenerGame(){

    Random r = new Random();
    int game = r.nextInt(100);

    if (game < 60){ // 60%
        // do something
    }
    else if (game < 79){ // 19%
        // do something
    }
    else if (game < 93){ // 14%
        // do something
    }
    else { // 7%
        // do something
    }
}
```

You could change the precision to tenths of a percent by boosting the range to 0-999.